# iOS Push Notifications Apple Email

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, app-store-connect

I am developing an iOS app and when I sent a beta to iTunes connect for testing I received an email from Apple saying that I had push notification in my application but did not set it up.

My app does not support push notifications but something is using it and I am not sure how to find it so  I can remove it.  I am using the following frameworks: RSNetworing, FLAnimation, CMMapLauncher, SwiftyJSON, and fmdb.

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: check provisioning profile

Comment: I have same issue. I use cocoa Pods in that app, I thought maybe it caused to it. Do you use Pods in app?

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I do not use Cocoa pods.  I will check my profile.  As Munahil is saying it is probably an error on Apple's part.